# how to run global npm package using crontab?

Tags: linux, npm, cron

I have an npm package which is installed globally. If I call it from terminal using global package name from any directory it runs perfectly fine. If I add it in crontab it does not run. It runs from crontab only when I go the directory and call npm start. I want to run it using only a single word command on crontab. Please help.

`$ appName //runs fine from any directory`

`$ cd path/to/npm/package; $ npm start //runs fine`

crontab

`@reboot appName & #does not work`

`@reboot npm start -prefix /path/to/npm/package & #works fine`

Answer (score 0):

firstly i would advise you to verify whether you are using crontab or cron, since they might behave differently.

secondly, verify the foolowing:

- cron job is executed on behalf of the user which successfully able to run the global package. i.e. eliminate user permissions
- cron job might need to login to the user shell if you defined some stuff in the user environment to run the global package as you expect